# How to create if statement from curl command output (c++)

Tags: c++, curl

I am trying to get the output of the `curl` command to work inside of an `if statement`

I am new to C++ and don't know how I could do this.

```
int curlreq;
curlreq = system("curl localhost/file.txt");
string curlreqstring = to_string(curlreq);
if ((krxcrlstr.find("hello") != string::npos) ) {
    cout << "hello\n";
}
else if (curlreqstring.find("hello2") != string::npos) {
    cout << "hello2\n";
}
```

> I am doing this on Windows. The project is a console app C++ 20

All the above code is doing, is printing what the curl response is, but I need that as a variable to then determine what the program should do.

As you see I am getting the contents of a file from localhost, the file itself has a singular line.

Comment: Instead of calling curl from your C program, could you execute curl and pipe the output into your C program `curl localhost/file.txt | myprog`? Then you could just read the curl output as input here.

Comment: I suggest using [libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcurl%20c%2b%2b) from within your program instead of using `system` to start a separate program. If that seems too cumbersome, call `system("curl -o file https://...");` and then read `file` from your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) returns an `int` with an implementation-defined value. On many platforms, `0` means success and anything else means some sort of failure. I'm making this assumption in the below example.

My advice is to use [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) which is what the `curl` command is using internally. With a little setup you can make your program perform `curl` actions *and* receive what you get back into your program. If you do not have access to [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) or find it a bit hard to get started with, you could wrap your `system` command in a function which performs the `curl` command but directs the output to a temporary file which you read after `curl` is done.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
```

```cpp
// a simple class to remove the temporary file after use
struct file_to_remove {
    // remove "filename" when the object is destroyed
    ~file_to_remove() { std::remove(filename.c_str()); }
    const std::string& str() const { return filename; }
    const std::string filename;
};
```

```cpp
// A function to "curl":
std::string Curl(std::string options_plus_url) {
    // An instance to remove the temporary file after use.
    // Place it where you have permission to create files:
    file_to_remove tempfile{"tmpfile"};

    // build the command line
    // -s to make curl silent
    // -o to save to a file
    options_plus_url = "curl -so " + tempfile.str() + " " + options_plus_url;

    // perfom the system() command:
    int rv = std::system(options_plus_url.c_str());

    // not 0 is a common return value to indicate problems:
    if(rv != 0) throw std::runtime_error("bad curl");

    // open the file for reading
    std::ifstream ifs(tempfile.str());

    // throw if it didn't open ok:
    if(!ifs) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));

    // put the whole file in the returned string:
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};

} // tmpfile is removed when file_to_remove goes out of scope
```

With the above `Curl` function you can perform `curl` commands and get the response as a `std::string` which you can then use in your `if` statements etc.

Example:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) return 1; // must get an URL as argument

    try {
        std::string response = Curl(argv[1]);
        std::cout << response << '\n';

    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```